# picasso android image not loading

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, retrofit, picasso

I am trying to get images from an API, and I have written code but images are not loading in emulator

**Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    List<Flower> flowerList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://services.hanselandpetal.com").build();

        api flowerapi = restadapter.create(api.class);

        flowerapi.getData(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Flower> flowers, Response response) {
                flowerList = flowers;
                adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_file,flowerList);
                setListAdapter(adapt);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

In package model I have **flower class**

```
public class Flower {

    private  int productId;
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private  String instructions;
    private double price;
    private String photo;
    private  Bitmap bitmap;

    public Flower() {
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }

    public void setInstructions(String instructions) {
        this.instructions = instructions;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
```

}

In network package I have **api java class**

```
public interface api {
    @GET("/feeds/flowers.jason")
    public  void getData(Callback<List<Flower>>response);
}
```

And then I have **`adaptor java class`**

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flower> {

    String url="http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/";
    private Context context;
    private List<Flower> flowerList;
    public adapter(Context context, int resource, List<Flower> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.flowerList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_file,parent,false);
        Flower flower = flowerList.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv.setText(flower.getName());
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url+flower.getPhoto()).resize(100,100).into(img);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I am getting nothing on emulator and it says it failed. Is the fault in emulator.
I have included internet permission in manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be blowing up on your @GET annotation param "/feeds/flowers.**jason**"

try ".json"